# replacing a specific column value by searching for its variable using awk/sed utility

Tags: awk

There is a conf file and its contents are as below

```
ipaddr = 192.168.10.1
hostanme = test
homefolder = /home/user1
```

how do i replace the value of homefolder with a different value using the awk utility. I want to be able to search the conf file using the keyword "homefolder" and then replace its value . I do not want to pick this line using the line number. The configuration file may get more details appended in future and hence using line number may be inappropriate

Comment: is that awk or sed in the end?

Answer (score 2):

you may try:

```
awk -vVALUE=some_path  -F= '/homefolder/ { print $1 " = " VALUE }' yourfile
```

where `some_path` should be the new value

EDIT:
as suggested by @karakfa and @EdMorton, a better version could be:

```
awk -v new_path=some_path  -F' *= *' '$1=="homefolder" { print $1 " = " new_path }' yourfile
```

The difference is that the separator will be = surrounded by any number of spaces (thus there are no extra space on the ouput) and my version would have matched a line like `mainhomefolder = /home/xyz` when the test `$1=="homefolder"` will only match `homefolder` exactly.

Thank you for the comments

Comment: `... -F' *= *'  '$1=="homefolder" ...` is better.

Comment: Not putting a space between `-v` and your variable name makes the script unnecessarily gawk-specific. Use `-v var=value` instead of `-vvar=value` for portability to all awks. Also, don't use all upper-case variable names to avoid clashing with builtin variable names and obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using builtin variables when they're actually user-defined.